# Function stops to work when $http is inside it

Tags: angularjs, babeljs

I've got a pretty odd issue if I ask myself.
Currently I've got a function in my view which is something like this:

`<h3 ng-click="{{ vm.open(item.info) }}"> {{ item.title }} </h3>`

and a function in my controller looking like this:

```
open = (url) => {
  console.log(url);
}
```

This function works as intended it writes out the slug of the item from the view. But the issue comes when I try to add my API service or a simple `$http.get()` call. It seems to break the entire function because if I add this to the function:

```
open = (url) => {
  console.log(url);

  result.getOpportunity(url).then(result => {
    res = result.data;

    var modal = res.title;
    console.log(modal);
  });
}
```

Nothing gets printed out in the console. not even the first `console.log()` that worked so pretty just seconds ago.
Can anyone tell me what is going on? I don't get any error in either console or terminal but something do seem to be broken somewhere.

Worth mentioning is that I'm using an yeoman generator called **Angular fullstack** which uses Babel.

If I look into my `gulp serve`:ed  .controller.js file that when I use the function that works. the single console.log line my file contains this:

```
this.open = function (url) {
  console.log(url);
};
```

and when I use the longer function which doesn't work this is in the ouputted controller.js:

on the line where the function that works was this is now: `_initialiseProps.call(this);` and later on this function:

```
var _initialiseProps = function _initialiseProps() {
  var _this2 = this;

  this.open = function (url) {
    console.log(url);

    _this2.result.getOpportunity(url).then(function (result) {
      res = result.data;

      var modal = res.title;
      console.log(modal);
    });
  };
};
```

so Babel rewrites pretty much. but the most peculiar thing I noticed was that if I call `_initialiseProps.call(this);` explicit via the console I get returned `undefined` which do make some sense because the function `_intiliaseProps()` function does not contain a function called `call()`
but when I call `_initialiseProps(this);` from the console I get an error returned with this:

`post.controller.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_checkURLforHTTP' of undefined(…)`

Which is kinda funny or i dont know.. tearing my hair right now. Anyway, the _checkURLforHTTP function contains this in the code before babel had it's thing going:

```
_checkURLforHTTP = (img) => {
  if (img.indexOf('http://') > -1 || img.indexOf('https://') > -1 ) {
    return 'url("' + img + '")';
  } else {
    return 'url("http://HARDCODED-URL-HERE' + img + '")';
  }
};
```

and the same function in the babel-processed file is the following:

```
var _initialiseProps = function _initialiseProps() {
  var _this2 = this;

  this._checkURLforHTTP = function (img) {
    if (img.indexOf('http://') > -1 || img.indexOf('https://') > -1) {
      return 'url("' + img + '")';
    } else {
      return 'url("https://HARDCODED-URL-HERE/' + img + '")';
    }
  };
};
```

Obviously it is something i'm not doing right, but i dont seem to understand what it is im doing wrong. I think I've managed to break it down into a click function in the view using $http.get();

Comment: `<h3 ng-click="vm.open(item.info)"> {{ item.title }} </h3>`, pull out parenthesis

Comment: @Hitmands what do you mean with pull out parenthesis?

Comment: Context, please. What is `open = (url) => {`? A variable assignment? A property assignment? If it's the latter, it's counterproductive.

Comment: @zeroflagL it's an ES2015 arrow function. that line basically turns out into `function open(url) {}` or in my special case: `this.open = function(url) {}` as stated above. for more info: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-arrow-functions/

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.